# how to render webpage with multiple line text java spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, format

i want to render the page using JPA with mysql
finally i got the result but the formatting is not correctly so is there anyone know way to fix it?

```
ROOT - 기상 - 기압 - null ROOT - 기상 - 온도 - null ROOT - 기상 - 강수량 - null ROOT - 캘린더 - 최근1년 - null ROOT - 캘린더 - 최근5년 - null ROOT - 캘린더 - 최근10년 - null ROOT - 뉴스 - null - null
```

i got the rendering result it is problem that it didn't include "\n" so i want to get the result like this

```
ROOT - 기상 - 기압 - null
ROOT - 기상 - 온도 - null
ROOT - 기상 - 강수량 - null
ROOT - 캘린더 - 최근1년 - null
ROOT - 캘린더 - 최근5년 - null
ROOT - 캘린더 - 최근10년 - null
ROOT - 뉴스 - null - null
```

include multiple line so could you give me some advice?

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/Category")
@Slf4j
public class CategoryController {
    @Autowired CategoryRepository categoryRepository;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/all", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public String getCategoryList() {
        List<String> sj = new ArrayList<String>();
        //List<CategoryProjection> all= this.categoryRepository.findByCategory();
        List<CategoryProjection> list = this.categoryRepository.findByCategory();
    // loop i
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        sj.add(list.get(i).getLev1() + " - " + list.get(i).getLev2()+ " - "+list.get(i).getLev3() + " - " + list.get(i).getLev4());

    }
    String all = sj.stream().collect(Collectors.joining("\n"));
    System.out.println(all);
    return all;
    //log.info(query);
    //return "Test";
}
```

this is my code so how can i fix it for getting result which it sustain correct format
thank you!
 My java version JDK8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\n works with console applications, what you are returning is HTML. The way to break a line using HTML is the `<br>` tag.

Just replace the `\n` with `<br>` and it should work fine.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/Category")
@Slf4j 
public class CategoryController { 
@Autowired CategoryRepository categoryRepository; 
@RequestMapping(value = "/all", method = RequestMethod.GET) 
@ResponseBody 
public String getCategoryList() { 
List<String> sj = new ArrayList<String>(); //
List<CategoryProjection> all= this.categoryRepository.findByCategory();
List<CategoryProjection> list = this.categoryRepository.findByCategory(); 
// loop i 
for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) { sj.add(list.get(i).getLev1() + " - " + list.get(i).getLev2()+ " - "+list.get(i).getLev3() + " - " + list.get(i).getLev4()); } 
String all = sj.stream().collect(Collectors.joining("<br>")); 
System.out.println(all); 
return all; 
//log.info(query); //return "Test"; 
}
```

Sorry for poor formatting, I am on mobile.

Comment: @hognkun if my answer fixed your issue, please select my answer as the correct answer